# Using CSS overflow, clip-path, Got trouble only on Safari Mobile

Tags: html, css, overflow, mobile-safari, clip-path

I was trying to apply a parallax effect using the combination of clip-path and a fixed image. The effect worked well, as demonstrated in the following Github repo.

Github repo: https://falasol.github.io/overflow/

Demo Page: https://falasol.github.io/overflow/

As you can see in the following gif image, I was tapping the Lorem text on my iPhone and the image poped out, instead of poping out the text selector.

[The video of tapping the div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uuIR.gif)

This issue only occurred on Safari Mobile, worked well on Andriod phones and desktop Chrome inspector tool. My current assumption of this question is that the `overflow:hidden` is having some issues on Safari Mobile.

Please give me some suggestion on this if you have ever got this issue before :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't happen to me when I try it with my iPhone on Safari.

Maybe giving the next div a `position:relative;` and `z-index:1;` will fix it for you?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).